# First line missing in concatenation of SSH output

Tags: shell-script, ssh, sudo, string

I am trying to concatenate two strings in bash script but I am not able to get the expected result,

```
USERNAME="ubuntu"
MASTER="some IP"
KEYFILE="/Path/to/keyfile.pem"
STR1=`sudo ssh -q -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $KEYFILE $USERNAME@$MASTER -p 22 'sudo hostname'`
STR2=`sudo ssh -q -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $KEYFILE $USERNAME@$MASTER -p 22 "sudo grep search /etc/resolv.conf"`
STR2=`echo $STR2 | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $STR1
echo $STR2
STR3="$STR1""$STR2" #OR "$STR1$STR2" OR $STR1$STR2

echo  "$STR3" # OR $STR3


OUTPUT:
ip-10-30-209-xx
ap-xxx-1.compute.internal
ap-xxx-1.compute.internal
```

I am getting only the second string but the first string is getting ignored. Why I am not getting the expected result here ?

another interesting point is, for curiosity if I concatenate the strings in reverse order i.e `STR3=$STR2$STR1`, The output is even weird..i.e
`ip-10-30-209-xx.compute.internal`. I am totally confused here..

Comment: what does`"$STR1""$STR2"` give you?

Comment: The example works for me.  The usual pitfall is a variable which is substituted in one of the assignments

Comment: You code is incomplete. **A complete script is much more easy to test.** There is no reason not to include the assignment of `STR1` and `STR2`, so update your statement with that.

Comment: @Anthon Would it matter as long as `echo`ing the individual strings works?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check

Comment: These kinds of things are often caused by unexpected carriage return characters

Comment: But the example shouldn't do that--except that running `sudo` on the remote side is pointless because the operations do not require privilege.  But a failure would have shown up in echoing `STR1` and `STR2` (if OP reports it accurately).  Removing the `sudo` would improve the situation by eliminating prompts that OP may not be reporting.

Comment: Removing sudo also didn't help me. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @Fiximan Yes is does matter. There is often something wrong in the copy and pasting, where newlines or special characters get lost. That makes answering into a guessing game and degrades this Q&A site to an interactive helpdesk with posts that are unlikely going to help anyone but the OP, which AFAIK is not this sites objective.

Comment: FYI, it's not copy paste mistake, even if I execute individual command on command line, I still get the same weird result.

Comment: @Anthon That makes sense. Shouldn't these then be displayable by, e.g. `echo $var | cat -A`? Or one could check if anything remains after `echo $var | tr -cd '[:print:]'`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Since the question was edited, the example does have the purported symptoms — `ssh -t` → CR → first line invisible.

Comment: @Fiximan Better make that `printf %s "$var" | cat -A`, otherwise you're mangling the string before printing it.

Answer (score 2):

The second string isn't ignored, it's hidden. To see it, run

```
echo "$STR3" | cat -v
```

The problem is that `STR1` ends with a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character. That character tells the terminal to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line. It's emitted just before the normal newline (line feed) character. The reason it's emitted is that you told SSH to emulate a terminal with the `-t` option, so it's arranging for things to be displayed properly. This does not provide a useful result when you're capturing the output in a string.

The commands you show can be run as any user, so you don't need sudo. If you don't need sudo, you don't need `-t`.

```
STR1=`ssh -q -i "$KEYFILE" "$USERNAME@$MASTER" -p 22 'hostname'`
STR2=`ssh -q -i "$KEYFILE" "$USERNAME@$MASTER" -p 22 "grep search /etc/resolv.conf" | awk {print $2}`
STR3="$STR1$STR2"
```

If your real script absolutely needs sudo, strip off the carriage return characters.

```
STR=`ssh -t … 'sudo mycommand' | tr -d '\r'`
```

Combining ssh and sudo is cumbersome. It's easier to stick to SSH for all the privilege escalation. This requires allowing the root account to log in with SSH. Unlike what you may have read elsewhere, this isn't inherently insecure. [The risks of privilege elevation from local user to root tend to be overrated](https://xkcd.com/1200/)); if an attacker has access to a sudoer account, they have access to root anyway. However, to keep useful logs, it's better to restrict *direct* access to the root account. You can authorize access to root for local users only by putting the following directives in `sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin no
…
Match Address 127.0.0.1,::1
    PermitRootLogin yes
Match User root
     PasswordAuthentication no
     GSSAPIAuthentication
     KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
```

Then root will be allowed to log in over SSH but only with key authentication and only by rooting through localhost. Once you've set up the keys, you can then chain the SSH logins:

```
STR=`ssh … 'ssh root@localhost "mycommand"'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing us the output from your script, or there are some strange values in your STR2.

Update your script to end in:

```
#!/bin/bash


STR1="ip-10-30-209-xx"
STR2="a ap-xxx-1.compute.internal"


STR2=`echo $STR2 | awk '{print $2}'`
echo 'str1['$STR1']'
echo 'str2['$STR2']'
STR3="$STR1""$STR2" #OR "$STR1$STR2" OR $STR1$STR2

echo  'str3['"$STR3"']'
```

which gives:

```
str1[ip-10-30-209-xx]
str2[ap-xxx-1.compute.internal]
str3[ip-10-30-209-xxap-xxx-1.compute.internal]
```

then *stepwise* replace the assignments with your own